# load csv file at runtime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to upload csv files at the runtime. Means user will upload their csv files when the program is at running state. First the program will ask the user 'How many number of csv file you want to enter?' And after that it will create that much number of blank data frame. Now the program will ask for csv files to be uploaded by the user and the program will link those data frames one by one to the uploaded data frames.

I already have tried the below mentioned code. But the code is not working.

```
import pandas as pd

n=input("Please enter the number of CSV file you want to enter")
for i in n:
    pd.DataFrame[(df[i])]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand what you try to achieve with the blank data frames.

Nevertheless, for loading CSV files, you can use [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) method.

```
dataframes = []
n = int(input("Please enter the number of CSV file you want to enter"))
for i in range(0, n):
    csv_path = input("Enter the csv path: ")
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
    dataframes.append(df)
```

Comment: This code works completely fine. But this code store all csv file into a single dataframe. But I need different dataframe to store each csv file. Suppose user will give 2 as n. So two dataframe will be created...df1 and df2(suppose). Now first csv file will be stored into df1 and the second csv file will be stored into df2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, please, read the code again. Each CSV is stored in a new dataframe and this dataframe is added to a list of dataframes. Your first CSV will be in dataframes[0], second CSV in dataframes[1], etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the for loop to

```
newList = []
for i in range(0, n):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    newList.append(df)
```

then add it to a list so that the created dataframe do not lose data.